# Kubuntu 22.04. Could not delete files. Access denied

Tags: linux

I have two folders that I am unable to delete, RasCon_NS and joycontrol. Inside the RasCon_NS there is a joycontrol folder whereas joycontrol has a RasCon_NS folder in it.

It shows the "Access denied" error message every time I tried to delete them. I am also unable to perform any other operations on the files inside the 2 folders. I think the reason for this problem is that I installed these 2 apps that contain each other from 2 different GitHub sources.

Can anyone help on how to delete these 2 folders? Thank you.

Update:

Hi. Thank you for your suggestion @KamilMaciorowski. It is very helpful. As for what command gave me the error message it was the attempt to delete the folder using `CTRL+DEL` on the GUI and `sudo rm -d -r RasCon_NS`. I don't know much about commands. I am new to Linux :)

But as I was entering the `ls -ld` command you mentioned and preparing the output for this problem, I got the following output:

```
zedd@zedd-kubuntu:~$ ls -ld RasCon_NS 
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jun 16 21:52 RasCon_NS 
zedd@zedd-kubuntu:~$ ls -ld RasCon_NS/ 
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jun 16 21:52 RasCon_NS/
zedd@zedd-kubuntu:~$ ls -ld joycontrol 
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Jun 16 23:17 joycontrol 
zedd@zedd-kubuntu:~$ ls -ld joycontrol/ 
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Jun 16 23:17 joycontrol/
```

I did some research about the output, and it seems like I needed root permissions for this.

so I tried the command `sudo rm -d -r RasCon_NS` again and it worked! It is very weird. I don't understand why it worked because it didn't work before. It said `no such file or directory`, so I wonder why this time it worked...

Comment: (1) Regarding the `kubuntu` tag you used: I don't think the issue is specific to Kubuntu or Ubuntu. `linux` may be a better tag here. (2) You described and interpreted the problem, but we need hard data. Please [edit] and post the output of `ls -ld` for each directory and their parent directories. Note if e.g. `RasCon_NS` is a symlink then `ls -ld RasCon_NS` and `ls -ld RasCon_NS/` will give you different output; then post both. A `tree`-like output that shows relevant directory structure will also help. And the exact command that gave you `Access denied` along with its output verbatim.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have updated the question. I followed your suggestion and analyzed the output. It turned out I solved the problem by using `sudo rm -d -r RasCon_NS`, It is weird because I tried this command before, and it didn't work at all. Anyway, thank you so much. I still wonder why it worked this time...

Comment: "I don't understand why it worked because it didn't work before. It said no such file or directory, so I wonder why this time it worked..." @Zedd - it can only mean; you typed the dir path/name incorrectly, and/or you were issuing the command from the wrong dir. Paying close attention to return messages can help to quickly/easily resolve the silly little errors we all inevitably make in terminals... happy hacking! :-)

Comment: @user1138 - LOL. Thanks for the advice. :)

Comment: NP @Zedd! FYI - If you did want to confirm the issue/error for yourself, you can look back through your .bash_history file... https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/44997/how-to-use-bash-history-to-improve-your-command-line-productivity/

Comment: This is not likely to become a Q&A pair with any value.